# Problem with memory between functions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a header of a class A with a `NSDictionary *data;` in the interface, not as a property.

In one method I call another method of another class B that returns a `NSDictionary`, I make `data = [class method]`, and all is well.

Later, when `data` is populated, I try to access `data` from another method of A, and the app crashes.

If I make a retain on `data` in the previous method:

```
data = [class method];
[data retain];
```

It all works, but I now have a memory leak. Why does it crash?

Answer (score 4):

You have a crash in the first case because the dictionary returned is getting deallocated before you reference it; and a memory leak in the second case because you have a `-retain` without a corresponding `-release`.

Most methods that return objects return `autorelease`d objects.  That guarantees that the object will persist until the end of the current run loop, but at that time the object will be released (that's what `autorelease` does).  So if you want to keep the object alive beyond the current run loop, you have to retain it:

```
data = [[class method] retain];
```

But once you've retained an object, it's your responsibility to release it.  For an object instance variable, the right time to do this is usually in `-dealloc`:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [data release];
}
```

Now, you should also be aware that if you overwrite `data` with another value, you also have to make sure that the old value gets released properly.  That's one of the advantages of using properties: you can have the compiler write functions for you that take care of this.  If your property is a `retain` property, than setting the value with

```
self.data = newvalue;
```

will a) `release` the old value, b) `retain` the new value, and c) set your instance variable to the new value. You'll still have to release the value yourself in `dealloc` when your object is destroyed, though.

Comment: Don't forget to `[super dealloc];`, just to be politically correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a memory leak? If I understand your question, you should just have to do `[data release];` in your `dealloc` method of class A.